# Getting Access to PID in install4j / Mirth Connect

Tags: install4j, mirth

I am using Mirth connect which uses install4j to launch the program.

I am using the `mcservice` program and would like to get the pid of the launched application so that I can monitor it. How do I do this? Right now the service only has the standard `start`, `status`, etc commands.

Back in 2011 there seemed to be some indication that pid monitoring would be coming soon: http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/showthread.php?t=5509

Answer (score 0):

If you need get the the number of the process pid, you can do it by the terminal command:

```
$ pgrep mcservice
```

Also, you can store the pid number into a file and run the next command:

```
$ kill -9 `cat /path/to/file.pid`
```

In this case, you choosing the best solution for your issue. If you need something more complex you can view this link: [Simple Process Checker To Find Out If A Service Is Running or Not](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/monitoring/simple-process-checker-script/)